# Appending dynamically created elements is making a network request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to make an AJAX call, then create some new DOM elements using the response data, and append them to an existing DIV on the page.

Everything works fine, however, the jQuery append function is causing a network request to a URL (http://example.com/current-page/false).

The console points to this code in the jQuery library, specifically the line `target.appendChild( elem );`:

```
    append: function() {
        return domManip( this, arguments, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
                var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
                target.appendChild( elem );
            }
        } );
    },
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Comment: can you show the relevant parts of your code as well, please, where you make this ajax request and then call append?

Comment: must be something wrong in your code. please post some code and tell us your jQuery version.